# Wolfram Alpha - FourierParameters not working with discrete fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to calculate the discrete fourier transform using the signal processing convention. The documentation gives the followng example:

```
Fourier[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
```

Based on the docs I expected a result like this:

```
{21, -3 -5.19615i, -3 -1.73205i, -3 -1.73205i, -3 -5.19615i}
```

Instead, I got:

```
{
    FourierTransform[1, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, ω],
    FourierTransform[2, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, ω], 
    FourierTransform[3, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, ω],
    FourierTransform[4, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, ω],
    FourierTransform[5, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, ω],
    FourierTransform[6, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, ω]
}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working and how I can get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Wolfram|Alpha use the [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/) and choose "Create a New Notebook". Type in the command

```
Fourier[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]//Chop
```

in a cell and hit Shift-Enter. The result is

```
{21.,-3.-5.19615i,-3.-1.73205i,-3.,-3.+1.73205i,-3.+5.19615i}
```

as you expected.